# Building a DLL Class Library

Tags: c#, dll, com

I trying to build a dll with a method do send emails, to be used in another programming platform (open edge - progress), but it does not work, cause it shows me the error 0x80040154 (Class not registered). To build my dll project, i used [this tutorial](http://jumbloid.blogspot.com.br/2009/12/making-net-dll-com-visible.html):

Bellow, the whole code of my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace EnviaEmail
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual), Guid("61495415-e035-4bc5-bc00-70e46c9766b8")]
    public interface IMailFunctions
    {
        void EnviaMail(string fromMail, string toMail, string bodyMail, string subjectMail, string attachmentsMail, string smtpMail);
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), Guid("0262794c-1858-40d8-90ca-cfe765913d3c")]
    public class clsEnviaEmail : IMailFunctions
    {

        public clsEnviaEmail(){}

        [ComVisible(true)]
        public void EnviaMail(string fromMail, string toMail, string bodyMail, string subjectMail, string attachmentsMail, string smtpMail)
        {

            string[] attachmentsSplit = attachmentsMail.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
            // Create the mail message
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

            // Set the addresses
            mail.From = new MailAddress(fromMail);
            mail.CC.Add(toMail);

            // Set the content
            mail.Subject = subjectMail;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.To.Add(toMail);

            foreach (string s in attachmentsSplit)
            {
                if (s.Trim() != "")
                    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(s));
            }

            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(bodyMail))
            {
                mail.Body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            // Send the message
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpMail);
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: may I ask why you are building a .dll to send emails when you can just create a class and use the built in .NET Mail class `System.Net.Mail;` to do this.. also why are you re-inventing the wheel... there are way too many working examples out there on the web on how to use `using System.Net.Mail;`

Comment: DJ KRAZE, i am not exactly re-inventing the wheel. I´ll use this DLL in another ERP, another infraestructure. In my ERP, i do not have so many useful methods, like this one (sending of emails). I am sorry but, i have made a lot of research and nothing had solved my problem...it is unfare do give me a negative point for this question...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Also, you'll want to put your `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient` objects into `using` blocks.

Comment: ok have you actually checked the assmenbly to make sure that the ComVisible property has actually be set = true or are you assuming that the attribute will handle that..?

Comment: Yes, i set the ComVisible property to be true and i did sign the assembly. Also, i did set my platform to be x86.

Comment: You forgot [ComVisible(true)] on your interface so it isn't ever going to work.  But you didn't get that far yet, you haven't managed to register the DLL correctly.  The simplest way is Project + Properties, Build tab, tick the "Register for COM interop" option.  Focus on Step 4 in the tutorial when this needs to run on another machine.

Comment: Hans, i already had set the attribute "Register for COM interop" for true and i did put the "[ComVisible(true)]" at my interface, but it still not working...

Comment: I'm assuming you want clsEnviaEmail  to be registered right and that the error message is calling out that class?

Comment: Exactly. is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Just for knowing, i´ve updated my code.

Comment: @erickles Run your IDE as Administrator.

Comment: Sarvesh, sorry but, did not work...it stills showing the message...is my class really correct?

Comment: Have you registered your COM dll ?

Comment: Yes, i already did. Actually, i found another way to do this, my ERP native language (Open Edge - Progress) can use the .Net libraries, what is great! Thank you guys for trying to help me!